# Segmentation fault while reading input with getchar()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, getchar

I have a silly problem while reading input with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


void read(char*** query)
{
    *query = (char**) malloc ( sizeof(char*) );

    int f=0;
    int i=0,j=0,c;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(!isalpha(c))
            continue;

        if(f==1)
            *query=(char**) realloc(*query,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));

        (*query)[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
        (*query)[i][j]=tolower(c);
        j++;

        while( (c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!=' '&&c!='\t'&&c!='\n' )
        {

            (*query)[i]=(char*) realloc((*query)[i],(j+1)*sizeof(char));

            (*query)[i][j]=tolower(c);
            ++j;
        }

        (*query)[i][j]='\0';

        ++i;
        f=1;
        j=0;

        if(c==EOF)
        {
            *query=(char**) realloc(*query,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
            query[i]=NULL;
            return;
        }
    }


    *query=(char**) realloc(*query,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
    query[i]=NULL;

}

int main()
{

    char** query;
    int i=0;
    read(&query);

    while(query[i]!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",query[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, I want to input any number of strings consisting of alphabetic characters separated by any number of spaces and tabs along a single line then press enter and give EOF signal.(CTRL+D under linux terminal.)  Then, it should output strings line by line fashion.
The problem is when I enter 3 strings it gives segmentation fault, but when I enter more or less strings no problem.
What might be the problem? 
Please, help!

Comment: Advice is simple in this case: Don't reallocate memory char-wise inside `getchar()` loops. Finding the error isn't that simple: Looks like there's some stack corruption going on.

Comment: Your function does too much. Split your problem to smaller pieces (functions) and have more meaningful identifier names. Also, don't cast return value of malloc/realloc in C.

Comment: `query[i]=NULL;` wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Good catch. Also, in the OP's logic, there should be a reallocation before `(*query)[i][j]='\0';` to make room for the null char.

Comment: Also, whenever you find yourself having more than two `*` in a data type, consider rewriting the program in a more readable way. If possible, also try to separate allocation, user input and the actual algorithm, they are 3 unrelated things.

Comment: @mualloc: Look at the other accesses with index `i`: It should be `(*query)[i]`. `query` itself is not an array, it is a pointer to a single pointer to pointer to char. You can reduce the level of indirection by redesigning your function from `void read(char***)` to `char **read(void)`.

Comment: @nualloc IRL you do't allocate 1 char on the heap, you allocate a buffer of n len, then if size exceeds n you reallocate. Otherwise you end up with lots of small allocated blocks in memory which is very ineffetive and time consuming. As a general rule try to minimize your allocation calls. Also there is no need to tow around the argument : it makes the code less readable, instead have a local variable and then at exit assign it to the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query[i]=NULL;` wrong. –  BLUEPIXY

@BLUEPIXY: Good catch. Also, in the OP's logic, there should be a reallocation before

```
(*query)[i][j]='\0';
```

to make room for the null char. –  M Oehm